# convert picturebox array to string or integer?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, picturebox

```
Public Class frmMind
        'Game Mastermind
        Dim pbxBoard(3, 9) As PictureBox
        Dim strColors() As String = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet"} 'Array for colors
        Dim intKey(4) As Integer 'Array for the mastermind's key
        Dim intCol As Integer = 0 'Subroutine for columns
        Dim intRow As Integer = 0 'Subroutine for rows
        Dim Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Violet As Boolean
        Private Sub frmMind_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                Dim Value As Boolean 'Sets a true and false thing to do stuff
'Gets a random number for a key that the use will not see

    Randomize()
    Dim intRand As Integer = ((Rnd() * 5))
    'Gets random numbers
    intKey(0) = intRand
    intKey(1) = intRand
    intKey(2) = intRand
    intKey(3) = intRand
    'Assigns a random number from 1-6 to each row

    Do Until Value = True 'Checks to make sure a number is not duplicated.
        If intKey(0) = intKey(1) Then
            intKey(1) = ((Rnd() * 5))
        ElseIf intKey(0) = intKey(2) Then
            intKey(2) = ((Rnd() * 5))
        ElseIf intKey(0) = intKey(3) Then
            intKey(3) = ((Rnd() * 5))
        ElseIf intKey(1) = intKey(2) Then
            intKey(2) = ((Rnd() * 5))
        ElseIf intKey(1) = intKey(3) Then
            intKey(3) = ((Rnd() * 5))
        ElseIf intKey(2) = intKey(3) Then
            intKey(3) = ((Rnd() * 5))
        Else
            'All if statements above gets a new number if one has already been used.

            Value = True
            MessageBox.Show(intKey(0) & " " & intKey(1) & " " & intKey(2) & " " & intKey(3))
        End If
    Loop
    'Sets the variables of strColors
    If intRand = 5 Then
        strColors(5) = "Violet"
    ElseIf intRand = 4 Then
        strColors(4) = "Blue"
    ElseIf intRand = 3 Then
        strColors(3) = "Green"
    ElseIf intRand = 2 Then
        strColors(2) = "Yellow"
    ElseIf intRand = 1 Then
        strColors(1) = "Orange"
    Else
        strColors(0) = "Red"
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub btnCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click


    If  Then
        MessageBox.Show("You good.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(":(")
        End If

End Sub

'Creates border around peg on click. Red 
Private Sub pbxPegR_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pbxPegR.Click
    Red = True
    If Red = True Then
        pbxPegR.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        pbxPegY.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        pbxPegO.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        pbxPegG.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        pbxPegB.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        pbxPegP.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End If
    Yellow = False
    Green = False
    Violet = False
    Blue = False
    Orange = False
End Sub

Private Sub pbxJ0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pbxJ0.Click
    If Red = True Then 'changes the box from an empty square to a square with a red dot/piece
        pbxJ0.Image = Image.FromFile("H:\VB.net\MasterMind\pictures\CboxR.png")
        pbxBoard(0, 9) = strColors(0)
    ElseIf Yellow = True Then
        pbxJ0.Image = Image.FromFile("H:\VB.net\MasterMind\pictures\CboxY.png")
        pbxBoard(0, 9) = strColors(2)
    ElseIf Orange = True Then
        pbxJ0.Image = Image.FromFile("H:\VB.net\MasterMind\pictures\CboxO.png")
        pbxBoard(0, 9) = strColors(1)
    ElseIf Blue = True Then
        pbxJ0.Image = Image.FromFile("H:\VB.net\MasterMind\pictures\CboxB.png")
        pbxBoard(0, 9) = strColors(4)
    ElseIf Green = True Then
        pbxJ0.Image = Image.FromFile("H:\VB.net\MasterMind\pictures\CboxG.png")
        pbxBoard(0, 9) = strColors(3)
    ElseIf Violet = True Then
        pbxJ0.Image = Image.FromFile("H:\VB.net\MasterMind\pictures\CboxP.png")
        pbxBoard(0, 9) = strColors(5)
    End If
End Sub
```

So the point of this code is to recreate a game called mastermind. the user enters four different colors on the first line and ties to guess the correct order and colors as the key(mastermind). We have it so the blank square will be replaced with what color the user selects. We cant figure out how to compare the new values/colors  to that of the randomizer/key. Or how to check that no color is used more than once. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at the Color structure defined in System.Drawing it defines a lot of known colors. Including the ones you name in `strColors`.

If you need a compare more than equality of the colors it get a little more complicated but start with checking the ARGB properties of the colors.

Simplified Console Program:

```
Imports System.Drawing

Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim a As Color = Color.Red
    Dim b As Color = Color.Orange
    Dim c As Color = Color.Turquoise

    CheckColors(a, a)
    CheckColors(a, b)
    CheckColors(c, Color.FromName("Turquoise"))

    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub

  Private Sub CheckColors(x As Color, y As Color)
    Console.WriteLine("Does " & x.Name & " equal " & y.Name & "? " & (x = y).ToString)
  End Sub
End Module
```

Output:

```
Does Red equal Red? True
Does Red equal Orange? False
Does Turquoise equal Turquoise? True
```